# How to not allow a window from changing size in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

```
public class Main extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    WelcomePage wp = new WelcomePage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(wp, 760, 450);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();       
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This is the code of the main class of my project. When it is run, the window opens in the specified size(760x450). From that page there is a lot of movement to other pages. When I return to the "WelcomePage" from any other page, it is not displaying in the specified size. Now its small in size. How can I prevent this automatic size changing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set

```
stage.setMinWidth(760)
stage.setMinHeight(450);
```

And it would be even safer to use setMax*() along with setMin*()

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMinWidth(double)
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaxHeight(double)

Comment: That problem solved. But now there is another one. When I run the code the window is displaying small in size. How it can be corrected ?

Comment: If the above answer solved your first issue kindly accept it and vote up.

Comment: For the second issue, kindly paste the WelcomePage code.